# Calculating Private Working set memory from WMI class methods

Tags: windows, wmi

I am using the following perl program which uses WMI class Win32_Process to determine memory usage of a process

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE qw/in/;
sub memory_usage()
{
    my $objWMI = Win32::OLE->GetObject('winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2');
    my $processes = $objWMI->ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process where Name=\'notepad.exe\'");
    my $memory = 0;

    foreach my $proc (in($processes))
    {
         $memory = $memory + $proc->{WorkingSetSize};
    }
    return $memory;
}
print 'Memory usage: ', memory_usage(), "\n";
```

WMI class Win32_Process and its properties are given on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Problem is that it calculates Working Set Memory and i want to calculate Private Working set memory, for which no property is defined on the linked page

Is there some way i can calculate Private Working set memory from this class?

Comment: And i have already used the PrivatePageCount property, but it does not return what is shown in PrivateWorkingSetMemory in Task Manager

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965225%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Change `Win32_Process` to `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process` and the `WorkingSetSize` property to `WorkingSetPrivate`. This will give you the private working set.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394323(v=vs.85).aspx