# Calculating Private Working set memory in perl

Tags: perl, wmi, wmi-query, win32ole

I'm basically trying to query private working set of a process in perl.
[I have already refereed this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773457/calculating-private-working-set-memory-from-wmi-class-methods)
The solution works great on win8/8.1 but for some reason the following line returns nothing on win7x64 and I have tried using IDProcess instead of Name, it still returns no process.

```
my $proc = $objWMI->ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process where Name=\'notepad\'");

$objWMI = Win32::OLE->GetObject('winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2');
$proc= $objWMI->ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process where Name=\'notepad\'");
foreach my $process (in($proc))
{
  print "abc";
  $out = $process->{WorkingSetPrivate};
}
```

So this thing doesn't work. 
Is there any different way of querying private working set size of a process in perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like on windows 7 64 bit the performance counter was corrupted. I finally founded this post [Corrupt Performance Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540961/3354265)

So I started cmd as admin and did lodctr /R (This basically reset your performance counters). After this, I was finally able to get the process, and this following code worked flawless :)

```
my $proc = $objWMI->ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process where Name=\'notepad\'");
```